# Unexpected token (38:8)

Tags: reactjs, web, react-redux

I am new to react js and I am still learning,

every time I restart my PC and I try to start Babel to convert JSX to ES6 I get the error below.

```js
C:\Users\Abdel\Desktop\React Course\indecision-app>babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presetes=env,react --watch
SyntaxError: src/app.js: Unexpected token (38:8)
  36 | const renderApp = () => {
  37 |     const template = (
> 38 |         <div>
     |         ^
  39 |             <h1>{app.Title}</h1>
  40 |             {app.options && <h3>{app.subTitle}</h3>}
  41 |             <p>{app.options.length > 0 ? 'here Are your options' : 'Options are empty'}</p>
change src/app.js
SyntaxError: src/app.js: Unexpected token (38:8)
  36 | const renderApp = () => {
  37 |     const template = (
> 38 |         <div>
     |         ^
  39 |             <h1>{app.Title}</h1>
  40 |             {app.options && <h3>{app.subTitle}</h3>}
  41 |             <p>{app.options.length > 0 ? 'here Are your options' : 'Options are empty'}</p>
```

I use these babel presets: react version 6.24.1 and env version 1.5.2

can get some help to prevent these errors in the future?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to import React in your file so it can transpile you JSX, put this at the top of your file `import React from "react";`.

https://hackernoon.com/why-import-react-from-react-in-a-functional-component-657aed821f7a

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added this line to my code and I still got the same error

Comment: You've misspelled `presets` as `presetes`.  If you're still struggling and for anyone else you can view this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576198/2466477